# can't join 2 queries in coldfusion

Tags: join, coldfusion

I've got a simple question for the coldfusion programmers, i wonder what i've done wrong in this code:

```
<cfquery name="get_account_plan" datasource="#DSN2#">
    SELECT 
        A.*,
        C.* 
    FROM
        ACCOUNT_PLAN A,
        #dsn_alias#.COMPANY C
    WHERE
        A.ACCOUNT_CODE= '#attributes.str_account_code#'
        OR A.ACCOUNT_CODE= '#attributes.str_account_code#.%'
        AND C.COMPANY_ID = A.ACCOUNT_ID
</cfquery>
```

why i get the outputs of this query different? for

```
<cfoutput>#get_account_plan.company_id#</cfoutput>
```

i get the value of 1 and for

```
<cfoutput>#get_account_plan.ACCOUNT_ID#</cfoutput>
```

I get the value of 419?

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: @ciaran u mean os of server? then microsoft server 2008 r2

Comment: It's hard to tell. We need more clues as to what columns exist in each table and what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you order of precedence in the where clause. Use parentheses to make the "or" and "and" definition more clear.

Comment: thx, but can u tell me exactly how to put these parentheses?!

Comment: If you are expecting the company_id and account_id to be the same values, then this is the approach:

( A.ACCOUNT_CODE= '#attributes.str_account_code#'
        OR A.ACCOUNT_CODE= '#attributes.str_account_code#.%' )
        AND C.COMPANY_ID = A.ACCOUNT_ID

Comment: @abrabr - You have not provided enough information. "Doesn't work" how ..?

Comment: @abrabr Post your edited code so that we can see what you did that still doesn't work, and tell us what it is that *didn't* happen, as well as what *did* happen. If you used the code that Paul provided, than the company_id and account_id should always match, since that AND condition must always evaluate to true for a record to be displayed.

Comment: @crosenblum below has an idea: try using specific joins. What you are doing right now may be interpreted as a cross join, so you are getting everything. Without more details on the tables and what you are seeing, that is the best ideas so far.

Comment: thank you all guys! i didn't make it work though :) but i hope i will figure something out.

Comment: Even with the old style join, it should not translate to a cross join because the query is joining on the company/accountid column. Though there may well be other columns involved that we do not know about. @abrabr - post the table structure and your query and I am someone can provide the proper query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specific a type of join, that is a lot more strict.

Either inner join, outer join, left outer join, right outer join.

That's why your data returned is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<cfquery name="get_account_plan" datasource="#DSN2#">
    SELECT 
        A.*,
        C.* 
    FROM
        ACCOUNT_PLAN A INNER JOIN #dsn_alias#.COMPANY C ON C.COMPANY_ID = A.ACCOUNT_ID
    WHERE
        A.ACCOUNT_CODE= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#attributes.str_account_code#" />
        OR A.ACCOUNT_CODE LIKE '#attributes.str_account_code#.%' <!--- Note LIKE. BTW, you need to sanatise this input! --->
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I think that's a given. What is it exactly you're trying to do?